# SQL Найти покупателей, которые совершали покупки до определённого времени, а после не совершали

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Необходимость определить покупателей, которые оформляли заказы до Июня 2020, а после больше не совершали покупок в Вашем магазине, т.е. не оформляли заказы, начиная с Июня 2020.
Нужно использовать INTERSECT или EXCEPT

Таблицы, которые имеются:

```
CREATE TABLE buyers
(
    buyer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    buyer_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    birthday DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    buyer_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES buyers (buyer_id),
    order_number INT NOT NULL, 
    order_date DATE NOT NULL,
    order_summa MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products
(
    product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200),
    price MONEY NOT NULL,
    type_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES product_types (type_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders_products
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES orders (order_id),
    product_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES products (product_id)
);
```

Делаю через EXCEPT, но никак не получается вывести нужного покупателя.
Мой запрос:

```
SELECT buyers.buyer_id, buyer_name
FROM buyers 
JOIN orders ON buyers.buyer_id = orders.buyer_id 
WHERE order_date <= '2020-05-31'
INTERSECT SELECT buyers.buyer_id, buyer_name
FROM buyers 
JOIN orders ON buyers.buyer_id = orders.buyer_id;
```

Comment: Вы уже второй вопрос по решению задач SQL задаёте. Почитайте про SQL. В инете полно инфы по этим темам.

Comment: @Виктор С другими данными получается данный запрос, вот с датой никак не могу нужное вывести.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавте туда Ваш SQL запрос

Comment: @Виктор добавил.

Comment: Через except вроде так: SELECT buyers.buyer_name
FROM buyers
LEFT JOIN orders ON buyers.buyer_id = orders.buyer_id
WHERE orders.order_date < '2022-06-01' and orders.buyer_id IS NOT NULL

except

SELECT buyers.buyer_name
FROM buyers
LEFT JOIN orders ON buyers.buyer_id = orders.buyer_id
WHERE orders.order_date >= '2022-06-01' and orders.buyer_id IS NOT NULL

Comment: Насчёт "and orders.buyer_id IS NOT NULL" надо проверить без этих условий

Comment: @Виктор спасибо. Можно без условий после AND. Таких результатов я добивался. Но они тоже не сходятся с тем, что должно получиться в итоге. То есть получается, что здесь вывелись все те люди, которые покупали товар до определённого момента, а после тоже покупали, но стоит условие по дате. А нужно вывести тех, кто после определённой даты покупки более не совершал. Думаю, тут нужен именно INTERSECT. Но вот как его применить.

Comment: первый селект - берёт тех кто до даты, второй - те кто покупал после даты. except - говорит если есть те кто до и после - не брать. Странно, что у Вас так выходит

Comment: *Нужно использовать INTERSECT или EXCEPT* Нафиг не нужно. Достаточно выбрать тех, у кого последняя (максимальная) дата покупки - ранее Июня 2020.

Comment: @Виктор *Через except вроде так* Если это учебное задание, то такой запрос точно будет отвергнут преподавателем. Скорее всего, со словами "Вы вообще не понимаете, как работает LEFT JOIN".

Comment: Тогда что-то такое: SELECT buyers.buyer_name
FROM buyers
LEFT JOIN 
(
              select buyer_id, max(order_date)  MaxDate
               from orders
               group by buyer_id) CMax
ON buyers.buyer_id = CMax.buyer_id and CMax.MaxDate < '2022-06-01'